# QGIS raster calculator failed due to 'No reference layer selected nor CRS provided Execution failed'

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, raster-calculator, spatial-filter

I'm trying to fix this by setting the CRS of my raster layer. From its property source information, it's Albert_Conical_Equal_Area, but somehow it just fits perfectly with another vector layer of EPSG 4326-WGS 84. When I set the raster to the same WGS84 as the vector layer, then it went crazy they departed far away from each other.
[image]

Or is there any alternative way to do the filtering? I only want to keep values ranging [21,24] from this raster.

Comment: You need to ensure both layers and the project CRS all match. You can export the raster to a new CRS, whatever one you want. Your project CRS, shown in the bottom right says EPSG:102008. Is this the correct CRS you want to use?

Comment: I'm in different? So the vector layer is WGS 84, and raster is Albert_Conical_Equal_Area (EPSG:102008). Which will you use? Thank you!

Comment: You should convert the layers to whatever CRS your study area is in. In this case, I would suggest to convert the raster to WGS 84 as your study area covers a large area of the USA.

Comment: Hi, dont change the crs of the raster layer. If you want it in another system export it or use a reproject tool. But has nothing to do with the error. You need to select the layer as a reference, or its crs as a crs, in the calculator dialog